# Creating a teamcity project from versioned controlled settings

Tags: teamcity

I have a git repository for a project with a `.teamcity` folder in it containing versioned teamcity settings. Assuming I have deleted this project from the teamcity server (by first disabling versioned settings and then deleting the project) how can I re-import it?

The use case here is being able to create a new project using a template generator, e.g. `yeoman` or `dotnet new`, and be able to import that easily into a parent TeamCity project.

Our current teamcity version is: TeamCity Enterprise 10.0.4 (build 42538), so things may have improved in later versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I have figured this out, these are the steps that worked for me.

1. Create a new project, making sure the Project ID is set correctly
2. Add a VCS root pointing to your repo that contains your project
3. Enable versioned settings making sure to select `use settings from VCS` and choosing the `Kotlin` settings format
4. Select "Import settings from VCS" when prompted

In more detail...

**Make sure the Project ID for your project matches what you have in your `.teamcity` file**

For example if your `.teamcity` file contains `.teamcity\MyAwesomeProject`, then you need to make sure your Project ID in teamcity is set to `MyAwesomeProject`.

**use settings from VCS**

If you don't tell TeamCity to use the vcs settings *by default* then it will do what it usually does and start checking things into source control for you.